# convert a list -class numeric- into a distance structure in R

Tags: r, data-structures, vegan

I have a list that looks like this, it is a measure of dispersion for each sample.

```
         1          2          3          4          5 
0.11829384 0.24987017 0.08082147 0.13355495 0.12933790
```

To further analyze this I need it to be a distance structure, the -vegan- package need it as a 'dist' object.

I found some solutions that applies to matrices > dist, but how could I change this current data into a dist object?

I am using the **FD** package, at the manual I found,

> Still, one potential advantage of FDis over Rao’s Q is that in the unweighted case
>   (i.e. with presence-absence data), it opens possibilities for formal statistical tests for differences in
>   FD between two or more communities through a distance-based test for homogeneity of multivariate
>   dispersions (Anderson 2006); see betadisper for more details

I wanted to use **vegan** *betadisper* function to test if there are differences among different regions (I provided this using element "region" with column "region" too)

```
functional <- FD(trait, comun)
mod <- betadisper(functional$FDis, region$region)
```

using *gowdis* or *fdisp* from FD didn't work too.

```
distancias <-  gowdis(rasgo)
mod <- betadisper(distancias, region$region)
dispersion <- fdisp(distancias, presence)
mod <- betadisper(dispersion, region$region)
```

I tried this but I need a list object. I thought I could pass those results to betadisper.

Comment: This does not look like a list, but rather a  vector. Distances are *between* sampling units, but  your narrative indicates that your numbers are for single SUs ("dispersion for each sample"). Such things cannot be transformed to distances. There cannot be a distance structure with 5 elements: 4 SUs have 6 distance among them, and 3 SUs have 3. With this background I would say that you cannot turn your vector to a `dist` object.

Comment: I modified the post to include more information, thanks for your help.

Comment: This was just the head of the object, I have as many distances as sites/communities -27- although as you said it seems like a vector instead of the usual dis object returned via _vegdist_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this: `FD::fdisp()` does not return dissimilarities. It returns a list of three elements: the dispersions `FDis` for each sampling unit (SU), and the results of the eigen decomposition of input dissimilarities (`eig` for eigenvalues, `vectors` for orthonormal eigenvectors). The `FDis` values are summarized for each original SU, but there is no information on the differences among SUs. The eigen decomposition can be used to reconstruct the original input dissimilarities (your `distancias` from `FD::gowdis()`), but you can directly use the input dissimilarities. Function `FD::gowdis()` returns a regular `"dist"` structure that you can directly use in `vegan::betadisper()` if that gives you a meaningful analysis. For this, your `grouping` variable must be based on the same units as your `distancias`. In typical application of `fdisp`, the units are species (taxa), but it seems you want to get analysis for communities/sites/whatever. This will not be possible with these tools.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.